approved Staging Ground review statistics
Are you curious on how the questions you approved in the Staging Ground are doing or do you want to see statistics for questions approved in the Staging Ground overall?
I wrote a user script that queries approved questions in the review history and collects some basic statistics about them.
Get it
You can view or install the script on GitHub.
How to use
As a Staging Ground reviewer, visit the Review history and select Approve and post on main site. If the script is installed, an approved question stats button should appear.

After clicking the button, you should be asked how many pages of the review history to check. If you enter 1, it will check all posts shown on the current page. For any positive number you enter, it will check that amount of pages starting with the current page (e.g. if you are on page 2 and you enter 5, it will check pages 2 up to (including) 6 which totals to 5 pages.
After entering the number, it requests these questions, and tells you the following statistics:

number of checked posts (excluding posts with errors)
average score per post
average amount of answers per post
average views per post
fraction of questions deleted after publishing (if any exist)
fraction of questions closed after publishing (not counting duplicates)
fraction of questions closed as duplicates after publishing


Warning
This scripts requests all posts listed in the amount of history pages to be checked. This would typically amount to 51 requests per page.
Use this script with care and be aware that checking many pages will result in a significant amount of requests being sent.
I don't take responsibility for issues due to rate-limiting/sending too many requests.
Limitations
There is currently a bug in the Staging Ground that doesn't allow approving some questions while still creating an entry in the review history. This script doesn't account for that issue which can result in the following problems:

If a post is queried but now published, the script will show it as an error (and doesn't count the question):

If the bug happened and (for some reason) the post was successfully approved afterwards, that post may be counted multiple times possibly skewing the statistics.

Aside from that, this script computes averages. This means it is affected by outliers (especially when it comes to views/post scores).
